# Two Separate Menus for Membership Plugin

Tags: mobile, responsive, desktop

Here's the run down:

1. I using the standard primary menu to display for both desktop and mobile devices.
2. I have another menu specifically for Members when logged in. The one for desktop is perfectly fine but I want a completely different menu for mobile.

So I have one primary menu for desktop and mobile and two more for when they are logged in to their members area. The one for desktop for members is fine but again I need a separate menu for mobile for members.

I hope I am making sense. I can provide a URL if you like.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you need to provide your code. You can place your code to Sandbox or Codepen, so that, we know exactly what you are up to. Second, which language are you sepcifically referring to? You can achieve this by using Javascript as well, but most of the time, CSS

Comment: My bad.  I am using Wordpress with Genises theme and Membership plugin.